Elastic Search contains special characters
We are using Elastic Search and trying to search for the below text.  I am using the direct search box to search
/-1/

I tried the below searches and nothing worked for
message: "\/\-1\/"
 message: "\\/\\-1\\/"

Need some help on how to search
Below is one example string/message available in the content and trying to search


As per this Documentation,

\():<>"* only these are the special characters that needs an escape character in the search.

Here, your text does not involve any of the above-mentioned special characters. So, there is no need to use Backslash (\) to escape the / or - characters. You can directly use the same text to search.
/-1/

Here is a sample demo where you can see it is giving proper results when there is no escape character \ for characters like / and - and whereas it needed an escape character for the special character : which listed in above documentation.


For some reason, the same is not working in my instance.  I tried message:/-1/ and also message:"/-1/"

Did you try messaage:*/-1/*?

When i try message:*/-1/* i see empty results

I have tried with this sample data https://i.imgur.com/f38gEUT.png. The query message : */-1/* is working fine for me. You can see the same here https://i.imgur.com/MEYZuk6.png. I think it's better to raise a support ticket for your issue if it's not working for you.
